# A basic question on infimum

Tags: real-analysis

let $E$ be a non-empty subset of a metric space $X$, define the distance from $x \in X$ to $E$ by 
$$ \rho_E(x)=\inf_{z \in E}d(x,z)$$

Now is it true that there exist a $z_0 \in \bar{E}$ such that $\rho_E(x) = d(x,z_0)$ ? How to prove ?

Actually, I want to prove that $\rho_E(x) \leq d(x,y) + \rho_E(y)$. I used these steps : $\rho_E(x) \leq d(x,z) \leq d(x,y) + d(y,z)$. I need to use the fact that it is true for arbitrary $z$. How to proceed from here ?

Comment: No, it isn't true. Can you think of a counterexample in $\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: I guess I need to think of a distance metric which is not continuous. for the usual distance metric i guess it is true.

Comment: No, in $\Bbb R^2$ with the standard topology (a metric space), it is not true.